# How to copy data from table on webpage and paste in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to copy data from a table on a webpage and paste it into excel. For now my code does the following:

1. Looks up the current date in the sheet.
2. Checks if the cell rightward to it (where the data needs to be put in) is empty or not.
3. If it is empty, it opens up a webpage which already contains the table.

```
Sub FindDate()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim hTable As Object
    Dim myIE As New Application


    Set IE = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")

    For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Range("c1:C269")
        If Cell.Value = [Today()] Then
        Cell.Select
        End If
    Next
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Select
    
    If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
        IE.NAVIGATE "https://xyz.de/Reporting?NavigationId=163&ReportDateId=20210908&StartDateId=20210908&BankstructureIds=117324,117326&IncludeIte=true"
    Else
        MsgBox "Values for today are already filled"
    End If

End Sub
```

I am unable to code the part where it identifies the table and copies it into the excel. Another way is to click the export button on the webpage and download the table as an excel and then copy it. But I dont know how to click the button via VBA. I know it requires me to enter the source code of the link but I have no clue how to go about the second way.

Comment: Have you looked at PowerQuery? From the Excel menu choose Data, then From Web, and follow the wizard. It does a good job of getting tables into Excel with a little patience.

Comment: I have tried that. Unfortunately it would not work in my case as the website is an internal company website and has many security layers. I can access it directly with this code with my company computer. Also, i need to make the macro as such that it copies the date for a lot of dates.  Not just the current date. So it would be a long job.